# need a faster version of substr in perl or other suggestion

Tags: perl

Does anybody have any ideas on how to speed up this perl code?

I want to keep the way this loop works by eating each match and starting the match again at position zero of the string on the next loop iteration... the reason why i need it this way is because i'm matching language constructs that span multiple lines..

The problem i'm having is that i'm reading a really large file that has thousands of lines of `define... and I think the call to substr is slowing it down... Looking for alternative ways of doing this that are much faster..

```perl
#!/bin/perl

$vlog = "out/tb_asc.sv";

open(my $F, "$vlog") || die("cannot open file: $vlog\n");
@lines = <$F>;
for(my $i=0; $i < @lines; $i++) {chomp($lines[$i])};
$bigline = join("\n", @lines);
close($F);


$movingline = $bigline;

sub nextline($) {
    @c = split(/\n/, $moving);
    $c = $c[0];    
    chomp($c);
    return $c;
}

print ">> << START\n";

$moving = $bigline;
$moving =~ s|//.*$||mg;
$moving =~ s|\s+$||mg;

while(1) {    
    
    # Blank Linke    
    if ($moving =~ /\A$/m) {
#        print ">> blank\n";
        $moving = substr $moving, $+[0]+1;
        next;
    }
    
    # timescale
    if ($moving =~ /\A\s*`timescale\s+\w+\s*\/\s*\w+$/m) {
        print ">> timescale\n";
        $moving = substr $moving, $+[0];
        next;
    }
    
    if ($moving =~ /\A\s*`define\s+(\w+)\s+(.*)$/m) {
        $def = $1;
        $val = $2;
        print "define: $def $val\n";
        $moving = substr $moving, $+[0];
        next;
    }

    if ($moving =~ /\A\s*`ifndef\s+(\w+)$/m) {
        $def = $1;
        $val = $2;
        print "ifndef $def\n";
        $moving = substr $moving, $+[0];
        next;
    }
    
    if ($moving =~ /\A\s*`ifdef\s+(\w+)$/m) {
        $def = $1;
        $val = $2;
        print "ifdef $def\n";
        $moving = substr $moving, $+[0];
        next;
    }
  
    if ($moving =~ /\A\s*`else$/m) {
        $def = $1;
        $val = $2;
        print "else\n";
        $moving = substr $moving, $+[0];
        next;
    }
    
    $c = nextline($moving);
    print "\n=> processing:[$c]\n";
    
  
  die("parse error\n");
}
```

Comment: Instead of using substr and \A to match start, use /g modified and \G as start. This way you can work on the same string all the time, which is way more efficient. To cite from [perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Assertions): *"\G     Match only at pos() (e.g. at the end-of-match position
       of prior m//g)"*.

Comment: `for(my $i=0; $i < @lines; $i++) {chomp($lines[$i])};` is easier to write `chomp(@lines)`. But really, what is the point of first removing the newlines with chomp, and then putting them back with join? And if you're going to slurp the file into one string, then its better to do `my $bigline = do { local $/; <F> };`. Disable record separator and read all lines.

Comment: Instead of combining each if-match with `next`, use a proper if-else structure: `if () { ... } elsif (...) { ... }`. And all this global variable usage makes your program really hard to follow, and hard to debug. The first time you use that nextline sub you will throw away all other lines in the file except the first one. Which is okay, I guess if that is what you want, but you have spent a lot of code earlier on splitting and chomping and joining, so feels like you are wasting some effort here.

Comment: Sometimes when you use `$1` and `$2` inside the if clauses, you have only 1, or no captured value (i.e. $1 or $2 is undef). That seems like a bad idea, and likely to confuse yourself and others, leading to bugs. Especially since you are using global variables. Also, you never use the variable `$movingline`